# Unable to get PHP mail function to work

Tags: php

Trying to implement a simple php mail function using the following code before I add it to my site. Receive this error

Error: 1

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

```
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
        die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $to = "admin@gmail.com";

    $message = "G'Day!]

    Your personal account for the Project Web Site
    has been created! To log in, proceed to the
    following address:

    http://www.example.com/

    Your personal login ID and password are as follows:


    You aren't stuck with this password! You can change it at any time after you have logged in.

    If you have any problems, feel free to contact me at <you@example.com>.

    -Your Name
    Your Site Webmaster
    ";



    $sql = mail($to,"Your Password for Your Website",$message,"From:Your Name <you@example.com>");

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Email has successfully been sent!";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br/>" . $conn->error;
    }



    $conn->close();

?>
```

Just looking for any sort of insight or glaring error im making or if im doing it completely incorrectly. Thanks.

Comment: First major mistake is your use of `$sql = mail()` which will return a boolean value not a query.  After that, you might need to check your mail logs to see if an email has actually been sent or not.

Comment: What on Earth are you trying to do with the result of the `mail()` function there?  What is `$conn`?  Why are things called `$sql`?

Comment: uh, exactly how do you think that the boolean false/true that `mail()` returns could **EVER** be used as a db query? So yes, glaring problems, and you're doing it completely incorrectly. query calls never return a boolean `true` either, so you will ALWAYS say the query failed, because it is literally impossible to ever get a true back. query calls either return a statement handle, or a boolean FALSE.

Comment: Also, you're sending to admin@gmail.com and using the person's name as the sender.

Comment: @dhool I would recommend you check the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

Comment: that's crazy code man

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't use the $sql in a good way.
Below the things you need for this email

```
$servername = "localhost";
$dbusername = "dbname";
$dbpassword = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

            // Create connection
            $conn = new mysqli($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
            // Check connection
            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            } 
            // END CREATING CONNECTION
```

To select information from DB:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);


                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    // output data of each row
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
                        $username = $row['username'];
                        $email = $row['email'];
                    }
                }
```

Email format:

```
    $to = "$username <$email>";
    $subject = 'Subject';
    $message = "<html>Hello $username, <br /><br />
        YOUR MESSAGE
        </html>";

    $mimeheader = 'MIME-Version: 1.0 '."\r\n".
                'Content-type: text/html; charset="iso-8895-1" '."\r\n".
                'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit '."\r\n";
    $mimeheader = 'From: YOURNAME <YOUREMAIL> '."\r\n";


    $mimeheader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $mimeheader .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    if( mail($to, $subject, $message, $mimeheader) ){


    }else{
        echo 'Mail not delivered.';
    }
```